# How can I get the correct time from NTP server in C++?

Tags: c++, time, client, difference, ntp

I am trying to get a real time from NTP internet server.
There are so many codes on web about this questions.
so I scraped codes and modified something and run the codes.
But the time difference between the actual time(Mar 2020) and the ntp server time(Dec 2008) is too large.
What's wrong?
Here are my codes.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

char *hostname = (char *)"time.windows.com";
int portno = 123;
const int maxlen = 1024;
__int64 i;
char msg[48] = { 010,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
char  buf[maxlen];

struct protoent *proto;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
int s;
time_t tmit;

proto = getprotobyname("udp");
s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, proto->p_proto);
perror("socket");

memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(hostname);
server_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

printf("sending data..\n");
i = sendto(s, msg, sizeof(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
perror("sendto");

struct sockaddr saddr;
socklen_t saddr_l = sizeof(saddr);
i = recvfrom(s, buf, 48, 0, &saddr, &saddr_l);
perror("recvfr:");

tmit = ntohl((time_t)buf[4]);
tmit -= 2208988800U;

char temp[256];
ctime_s(temp, sizeof(temp), &tmit);
std::wcout << L"time is " << temp << std::endl;
```

Comment: First thing that I've noticed is wrong expression: `tmit = ntohl((time_t)buf[4]);`. You are converting char variable (which max value is 127) to time_t.

Comment: If you are sure about the position of time in frame you can try `tmit = ntohl(*((time_t*)&buf[4]))` but it's much safer to use packed structures in such scenarios.